# SUM of two Decimal values from subreport and mainreport. Possible in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm having a trouble about the sum of two fields.

**In my main report**

```
Beginning Balance : ___________
Outstanding Balance : 100
```

**In my subreport**

```
Payment: 50
```

Basically, I have to add the Payment and the outstanding balance to get the Beginning balance. I've been trying to test this out but I keep on failing :'(  i have to present it to my client on Monday.

Comment: return value from subreport add it in main report.

Comment: @user2870747 Yes, it is possible